# Parallel sort slower than serial sort

Tags: java, sorting

I was reading about the new features in Java 8 and one of them was the new Arrays.parallelSort() method. I made some tests sorting an array of doubles and one of Strings and for Strings the parallelSort was much slower.

Here is the content of a test method for Strings:

```
    final int size = 10000;
    final String[] values1 = new String[size];
    final String[] values2 = new String[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        values1[i] = Integer.toString(i);
        values2[i] = values1[i];
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(values1));
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(values2));
    final Comparator<String> comparator = (o1, o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1);

    long startTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(values1, comparator);
    long endTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Arrays.sort: totalTimeInMicro= " + ((endTimeInNano - startTimeInNano)/1000));

    //parallel sort with java 8
    startTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.parallelSort(values2,comparator);
    endTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Arrays.parallelSort: totalTimeInMicro= " + ((endTimeInNano - startTimeInNano)/1000));
```

The result was:

`Arrays.sort: totalTimeInMicro= 11993`

`Arrays.parallelSort: totalTimeInMicro= 89823`

I also tried this code on another computer and the result was the same (25608 vs 808660). The computer I run the tests has an i5-2500 CPU. Do you have any idea why I get this kind of results?

Comment: Could be due to thread creation overhead. Try sorting even larger arrays: it might be possible that there is an array size for which parallel sort is faster.

Comment: Timing a single invocation (without even ramping up) isn't going to tell you much.

Comment: 1. You should give a warm-up run before doing any micro bench-marking. 
2. `Arrays.parallelSort()` uses `fork-join` framework. So it is directly related to the number of cores on a system (hence it is *architecture-dependent*). i-5 has 4 cores, so ideally `parallel sort` should be faster.

Comment: @Elemental The list isn't in the correct order though, as the elements are compared as strings, so `"1000"` < `"2"`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) may be of help in writing a more informative benchmark.

Comment: I am running a client JVM and it seems that after 200k values, the  parallelSort starts to run faster.

Comment: @Slimu Or maybe that's where JIT kicks in, or who knows. Reducing the noise of the measurement is tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This benchmark tells you hardly anything. The most important things for a microbenchmark are

- Give the JIT a chance to optimize the code by running the tests multiple times
- Use different input sizes
- Print some of the results, to prevent the JIT from optimizing away the whole calls

There are some more points to consider - in fact, *many* more points. You should consult [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for further information.

For really "profound" information, you should use tools like [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) or [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). But even with little effort, one can create a microbenchmark that shows a rough indication of how the actual performance would be. So one of the **simplest** forms of a microbenchmark could look like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ParallelSortSpeedTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int size=100000; size<=1000000; size+=100000)
        {
            final String[] values1 = new String[size];
            final String[] values2 = new String[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                values1[i] = Integer.toString(i);
                values2[i] = values1[i];
            }
            Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(values1));
            Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(values2));
            final Comparator<String> comparator = (o1, o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1);

            testSort(values1, comparator);
            testParallelSort(values2, comparator);
        }
    }

    private static void testSort(
        String array[], final Comparator<String> comparator)
    {
        long startTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
        Arrays.sort(array, comparator);
        long endTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Arrays.sort        : totalTimeInMicro= " + 
            ((endTimeInNano - startTimeInNano)/1000)+", first "+array[0]);
    }

    private static void testParallelSort(
        String array[], final Comparator<String> comparator)
    {
        long startTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
        Arrays.parallelSort(array, comparator);
        long endTimeInNano = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Arrays.parallelSort: totalTimeInMicro= " + 
            ((endTimeInNano - startTimeInNano)/1000)+", first "+array[0]);
    }

}
```

This is a reasonable option,  considering the trade-off between the effort of getting a JMH benchmark up and running, and the reliability of the results. This test will print something like

```
...
Arrays.sort        : totalTimeInMicro= 530669, first 999999
Arrays.parallelSort: totalTimeInMicro= 158227, first 999999
```

Showing that the parallel sort *should* be faster, at least.

Comment: I made some more tests, using an initial size of 50k and increasing the size by 50k up to 10 millions. For the final size, I got the following result:

`Arrays.sort: totalTimeInMicro= 653260

Arrays.parallelSort: totalTimeInMicro= 257168`

Comment: I made the mistake of considering single runs with different values good enough for a simple test. I'll read more about micro-benchmarking.

Comment: Genuine question: Shouldn't you only Shuffle once, and then let the other array be a copy of that shuffle? So that you are comparing the exact same thing. Upvoted.

Comment: @Peheje Basically, you are right. I could try to defend me: This part of the code was basically taken from the question. *Theoretically*, it *could* happen that one shuffle causes an order of the strings that is "easier to sort" (e.g. alrady in ascending order). But considering that there are 10 runs with up to 1 million strings, and the `shuffle` generates a truly (pseudo)random order, I'm pretty sure that differences will be not measurable here. However, one could shuffle the first list, and then use `values2 = values1.clone();` to be on the safe side - or do a *real* benchmark with JMH ;-)

Comment: Cool thanks for the clarification!